# Process Scheduling Math

Tags: c, math, process, job-scheduling

I have a program that prints out 'A' 3 times, with 1 second delay between each print. Calling this program once would take 2.00 seconds.

Imagine I created a job scheduler that executed a process for .5 seconds then switched to the next process (temporarily pausing the previous one until it reached it again). If I started the program mentioned above twice and ran this job scheduler on these two proceses, wouldn't it take 4 seconds total?

I've tested this but at the moment, it is being timed at 2.5 seconds. Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Can you show us the scheduling code?

Comment: Maybe there is an implementation problem in the program. For instance, if you are getting a one second delay by testing whether `(timeNow > timeOriginal + 1)`, then as soon as you switched back to the original program this condition would test as true, as several seconds have advanced.

Answer (score 3):

The two jobs are probably running in parallel.  Here is a break up of what's happening:

1. Time 0 - Task 1 started
2. Time 0.5 - Task 2 started [both running]
3. Time 2.0 -  Task 1 Finished [ Task 1 ran for 1.5 seconds already]
4. Time 2.5 - Task 2 ran for 0.5 second more to completion.

Answer (score 0):

That entirely depends on the mechanism used to effect the one-second delay.

If it uses an actual clock that continues ticking even when the job is suspended, then there's no reason to think that time-slicing two such jobs should take twice as long as running one. In fact, running two jobs like you describe should take just over two seconds. The reason you're seeing 2.5s is probably due to the fact that the granularity of your scheduler is 0.5s.

On the other hand, if the delay is effected by spinning for a pre-determined number of CPU cycles, then the execution times would indeed add up. However, no sane `delay` routine designed for a general-purpose CPU would be implemented in this manner.

Comment: The delay in the program uses wait(1) to wait 1 second before printing. Would this pause if the process is sent a SIGSTOP?